# Does certain fonts can't be used for embedding in css?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to embed a font and I tried it before and it works. My code was just a regular one which is accepted by other browsers.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: KozGoPr6N;
    src: url('../font/KozGoPr6N-Bold.otf')  format('opentype');
    src: url('../font/KozGoPr6N-Bold.woff')  format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

But then when I am trying to embed [ShinGoPro](https://github.com/skyavy-cebu/DoubleClick/blob/master/web/fonts/A-OTF-ShinGoPro-Regular.otf?raw=true) it doesn't work at all.
This is my code before:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ShinGoPro-Bold;
    src: url('../fonts/ShinGoPro-Bold.otf')  format('opentype');
    src: url('../fonts/ShinGoPro-bold.woff')  format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I use [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) and still it doesn't work.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'a-otf_shin_go_pror';
    src: url('../fonts/shingopro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/shingopro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/shingopro-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/shingopro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/shingopro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/shingopro-regular-webfont.svg#a-otf_shin_go_pror') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Somehow I've been thinking if this font is not applicable for embedding but then I do need to get this font to work for my web page. Does this font cannot really be embedded in CSS? Is there anything I can do for this to work?

**EDIT**

My code is for crossbrowser and it doesn't work at all. I linked the file of the font so that people can try what I'm trying to do. I already tried using [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) and it doesn't work at all.

> Does this font cannot really be embedded in CSS? Is there anything I can do for this to work?

^ This is referring to all browsers.

Comment: you can use any fonts, use this site to generate your css http://www.font2web.com/

Comment: @LuckyChingi That site has an upload limit of 512kb and my font is around 3mb. So I don't use that site.

Comment: @ThisClark As you can see I have 2 kinds of code one is `font-family: ShinGoPro-Bold;` and `font-family: 'a-otf_shin_go_pror';` generated by fontsquirrel. There's no difference at all both are not working.

Comment: @ThisClark Yes because I needed a shorter name. Is it not okay renaming it?

Comment: @ThisClark I have another font that is working okay after renaming it. So I thought it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ThisClark All is well my friend and still not working in other browsers when I put other format. I need to make the font work in all of the browser.

Comment: @user3771102 After a while looking at this problem, I agree with you - the font appears to just not work. In spite of deploying it exactly as I have done with my other fonts, I can not get this font to work. I did notice that the TTF and OTF formats appears differently when viewing them side-by-side in Windows Font Viewer. I've hit my personal limit with this problem. All I have left in thought is to try obtaining the same file from another source and see if you get a matching side-by-side comparison after conversion.

Comment: Yup. Thank you for taking your time analyzing my problem. I am also wondering why it doesn't work when my other fonts is okay. I am also considering that the font is a japanese font and maybe its one of the reasons why it doesn't work like the other fonts.